# nodejs on exit (SIGTERM/SIGINT), get a promise working (with sails)

Tags: node.js, promise, sigint

I'm trying to add an option to gracefully end a sails server (that runs inside a docker). This requires me writing something to the database so that other copies of the server know this particular server has "died".

Following nodejs process I could intercept the stop command with:

```
const util = require("util");
const setTimeoutPromise = util.promisify(setTimeout);
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  endMe('exiting - sigterm');
});


process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  endMe('exiting - sigint');
});

function endMe(msg) {
  console.log('trying to end it');
  setTimeoutPromise(1).then(function (res) {
    console.log('killed it');
    sails.lower(function(err) {
      console.log(msg);
      process.exit(err ? 1 : 0)
    });
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("error occured");
    console.log(err);
    sails.lower(function(err) {
      console.log(msg);
      process.exit(err ? 1 : 0)
    });
  })
}
```

please ignore the triviality of setTimeoutPromise - it's there for an mvce. Ultimatelly I wish to write some data to a database on exit. (the server is meant to run in a cluster, so by writing to a database I notify that the server has gracefully ended).

What I do see in the console/terminal is:

```
trying to end it
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which shouldn't be the case. - It means that the promise is never executed.

Comment: If you're seeing "trying to end it" but neither "killed it" nor "error occurred", then the only realistic conclusion is that the promise returned by `setTimeoutPromise(1)` (or what that expression represents) remains pending - ie it follows neither its success nor its error path.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 exactly - but why and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "prevent". You could (maybe should) fix the promise-returning function such that it is guaranteed to settle. If you can't do that then you can race the returned promise against a timeout in your `endMe()` function thereby giving you a promise that will at worst reject with a "timed out" error.

Comment: It is guaranteed to settle, - it's a "built in" and simple promisified callback that waits for 1 ms.  I've used it often, if I use a manual promise I can see it doesn't even *enter* the promise, rather it quits before the promise starts executing.

Comment: Thoughts: Maybe under SIGTERM/SIGINT conditions, the callbacks are given an opportunity to run before the server shuts down - however that concession only applies to code that runs synchronously in those callbacks, not to any later tasks/micro-tasks, hence the `then()` callbacks have missed the boat.